# Android Google Maps obtaining user location on emulator with 3G?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, 3g, android-maps

Is it possible to use 3G (from USB 3G) to implement a obtain location function ? I tried with the map which is installed on Android by default, when I tap on show my location it couldn't obtain my location with 3G connection.

From this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html. I see cellID. Is CellID available with 3G or only available with cell phone ?

Thank in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a setting in the emulator config that will allow for location via network. If you are using the eclipse plugin, it will be in the Run/Debug settings for the emulator. Also, check your location and security settings on the emulator. Because it is just a jvm running android, you still need to allow the phone to find your location via network. Hope this helps.